# Why I have the following error require is not defined with express?

Tags: node.js, express

My server.js file return the following error: **ReferenceError: require is not defined**

**server.js**:

```
import express from 'express'
import { readdirSync } from 'fs';

const app = express()

// Route middleware
readdirSync('./routes').map((route) => 
    app.use('/api', require(`./routes/${route}`))
)

const port = 8000

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}`))
```

Note that in my package.json I use: "type": "module"
just to use **import** instead of **require**.

Comment: in the package.json I have this: 
"type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },

Answer (score 0):

Your file is ES6 JS, kind of .mjs file; and you're using both `import` and `require` (ES5). To use `require` in ES6 JS code, this module is good: `mjs-require`

Install `mjs-require` to use `require` function in ES6 code:

```
npm i mjs-require --save
```

To run .mjs file with `require` function enabled:

```
node --experimental-modules -r mjs-require yourfile.mjs
```

Comment: Thx @datdinhquoc, unfortunately this piece return the following error: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: oh no, u should install node.js correctly, the `node` is the command of node.js, it must be there